# Как создать эффект затвора камеры с помощью divs

Tags: javascript, css, html5, svg, svg-animation

Я попытался сделать круговую камеру затвора фотоаппарата, но у меня проблема с тем, чтобы заставить его выглядеть реалистично.

Вот как это должно выглядеть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ниже код, который я пробовал:

```js
let partAmount = 10;
let cont = document.getElementById('cont');
let parts = [];
for(let i = 1; i <= partAmount; i++){
  let partCont = createElement('div','partCont');
  let part = createElement('div','part');
  parts.push(part);
  partCont.appendChild(part);
  cont.appendChild(partCont);
  partCont.style.transform = 'rotate('+ 360 / partAmount * i+'deg) translatey(-250px)';
}
function createElement(tag,className){
  let elem = document.createElement(tag);
  elem.classList.add(className);
  return elem;
}
```

```css
#cont{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);

  border-radius: 50%;
}
.dia{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.partCont{
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: left top;
}
.part{
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-bottom: 3px solid gray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: rotate(60deg);
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="dia">
  <div id="cont">
  </div>
</div>
```

Первый «лепесток» должен быть ниже, чем последний, и выше, чем следующий.

Как это сделать?

Comment: может попробовать через `translate3d` / `perspective`?

Comment: @ThisMan попробуйте. Если ответ будет на уровне, - галочка и плюсы гарантированы :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Сниппет в этом ответе поддерживает разное количество створок диафрагмы.

В основе этого решения лежит [алгоритм нахождения точек пересечения двух окружностей](https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/voBwJm)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
let r = 80, 
    arc = (x,y,s) => `A${r},${r},0,0,${s},${x},${y}`,
    path = (i,d) => `<path transform='rotate(${i/+count.value*360})' ${d}></path>`;

function upd (val) {
    
    let step = Math.PI*(0.5 + 2/+count.value);
    let p1x = Math.cos(step)*r; 
    let p1y = Math.sin(step)*r;
    let cos = Math.cos(-val);
    let sin = Math.sin(-val);
    let c1x = p1x - cos * p1x - sin * p1y;
    let c1y = p1y - cos * p1y + sin * p1x;
    let dx = - sin * r - c1x;
    let dy = r - cos * r - c1y;
    let dc = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
    let a = Math.atan2(dy, dx) - Math.acos(dc/2/r);
    let x = c1x + Math.cos(a)*r;
    let y = c1y + Math.sin(a)*r;
    
    let edge = `M${p1x},${p1y}${arc(0,r,0)}${arc(x,y,1)}`;
    edges.innerHTML = bodies.innerHTML = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < +count.value; i++) {
        edges.innerHTML += path(i, `fill=none stroke=black d='${edge}'`);
        bodies.innerHTML += path(i, `fill=lightgray d='${edge}${arc(p1x,p1y,0)}'`); 
    }
};

upd(0.5);

addEventListener('mousemove', e => upd(e.y/innerHeight*1.04));
```

```html
<svg viewbox=-100,-100,200,200 style="height:90vh" id=svg>
    <g id=bodies></g><g id=edges></g>
</svg><br>
<input id=count type=range min=2 max=13 value=5 style="position:absolute;top:2px">
```

Comment: замечательный ответ. Я приму его. Были мысли у меня сделать звуковой щелчок, открывание диафрагмы и внутри изображение. При повторном щелчке другое изображение...

Comment: @Alexandr_TT я еще математику упростил не до конца, попозже обновлю, визуально ничего не изменится

Answer (score 16):

1. Решение заключается в том, чтобы учесть тот факт, что у вас
   симметричная форма, поэтому вы можете построить ее, используя два
   разных элемента, где вы применяете одну и ту же вещь, а затем
   поворачиваете один из элементов, чтобы создать иллюзию одной формы.

   Я буду использовать множественный фон и линейный градиент, чтобы
   создать это:

```css
.camera{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  margin:auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border:1px solid;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  --c1: transparent 55%,#000 calc(55% + 1px) calc(55% + 4px),grey calc(55% + 5px);
  --c2: transparent 40%,#000 calc(40% + 1px) calc(40% + 4px),grey calc(40% + 5px);
}
.camera::before,
.camera::after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:100%;
  width:50%;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(-153deg,var(--c1)),      
    linear-gradient(-107deg,var(--c2)),      
    linear-gradient(-73deg ,var(--c2)),      
    linear-gradient(-27deg ,var(--c1));
}

.camera::after {
  transform:rotate(180deg);
  transform-origin:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="camera">
</div>
```

2. Как вы можете видеть выше, мы почти близки к результату, и есть две
   пропущенные строки, которые мы можем добавить, используя
   дополнительный градиент, как показано ниже:

```css
.camera{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  margin:auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border:1px solid;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  --c1: transparent 55%,#000 calc(55% + 1px) calc(55% + 4px),grey calc(55% + 5px);
  --c2: transparent 40%,#000 calc(40% + 1px) calc(40% + 4px),grey calc(40% + 5px);
}
.camera::before,
.camera::after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:100%;
  width:50%;
  background: 
    linear-gradient( 153deg,var(--c1)) bottom/100% 43.5% no-repeat,    
    
    linear-gradient(-153deg,var(--c1)),      
    linear-gradient(-107deg,var(--c2)),      
    linear-gradient(-73deg ,var(--c2)), /* 180 - 107 = 73deg*/ 
    linear-gradient(-27deg ,var(--c1)); /* 180 - 153 = 27deg*/
}

.camera::after{
  transform:rotate(180deg);
  transform-origin:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="camera">
</div>
```

**Немного математики**

3. В случае, если нам нужен точный расчет, мы должны учитывать, что
   нарисованная внутри фигура является восьмиугольником:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из этого мы можем определить угол поворота. Первый будет - `45 градусов / 2 = 22,5` градусов.
Затем мы увеличиваем на 45 градусов, чтобы найти остальные:

Код станет:

```css
.camera{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  margin:auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border:1px solid;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  --p1:55%;
  --p2:40%;
  
  --c1: transparent var(--p1),#000 calc(var(--p1) + 1px) calc(var(--p1) + 4px),grey calc(var(--p1) + 5px);
  --c2: transparent var(--p2),#000 calc(var(--p2) + 1px)calc(var(--p2) + 4px),grey calc(var(--p2) + 5px);
}
.camera::before,
.camera::after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:100%;
  width:50%;
  background: 
    linear-gradient( 112.5deg,var(--c1)) bottom right/10%  14% no-repeat,
    linear-gradient( 157.5deg,var(--c1)) bottom      /100% 54% no-repeat,    
    
    linear-gradient(-157.5deg,var(--c1)), /* -135deg */    
    linear-gradient(-112.5deg,var(--c2)), /* -90deg */     
    linear-gradient(-67.5deg ,var(--c2)), /* -45deg */
    linear-gradient(-22.5deg ,var(--c1));
}

.camera::after{
  transform:rotate(180deg);
  transform-origin:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="camera">
</div>
```

4. Вы можете заметить, что нам понадобятся 2 дополнительных градиента,
   потому что будет больше пропущенных линий.

   Чтобы управлять формой, вы должны отрегулировать значения `color stops` (--p1 и --p2) и скорректировать размер дополнительных
   градиентов (все еще нужно найти связь между этими значениями)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.camera{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border:1px solid;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  --p1:55%;
  --p2:40%;
  
  --c1: transparent var(--p1),#000 calc(var(--p1) + 1px) calc(var(--p1) + 4px),grey calc(var(--p1) + 5px);
  --c2: transparent var(--p2),#000 calc(var(--p2) + 1px)calc(var(--p2) + 4px),grey calc(var(--p2) + 5px);
}
.camera::before,
.camera::after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:100%;
  width:50%;
  background: 
    linear-gradient( 112.5deg,var(--c1)) bottom right/var(--e1,10%)  var(--e2,14%) no-repeat,
    linear-gradient( 157.5deg,var(--c1)) bottom      /100% var(--e3,54%) no-repeat,    
    
    linear-gradient(-157.5deg,var(--c1)), /* -135deg */    
    linear-gradient(-112.5deg,var(--c2)), /* -90deg */     
    linear-gradient(-67.5deg ,var(--c2)), /* -45deg */
    linear-gradient(-22.5deg ,var(--c1));
}

.camera::after{
  transform:rotate(180deg);
  transform-origin:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="camera">
</div>

<div class="camera" style="--p1:65%;--p2:55%;  --e1:0;--e3:40%">
</div>

<div class="camera" style="--p1: 46%;--p2: 29%;  --e1: 26%;--e2: 35%;--e3: 62%;">
</div>
```

5. Мы можем легко перейти к любой форме многоугольника, добавив больше
   слоев и правильно рассчитав степень вращения.

   Пример с декагоном:

```css
.camera{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border:1px solid;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  --p1:60%;
  --p2:48%;
  --p3:38%;
  
  --c1: transparent var(--p1),#000 calc(var(--p1) + 1px) calc(var(--p1) + 4px),grey calc(var(--p1) + 5px);
  --c2: transparent var(--p2),#000 calc(var(--p2) + 1px) calc(var(--p2) + 4px),grey calc(var(--p2) + 5px);
  --c3: transparent var(--p3),#000 calc(var(--p3) + 1px) calc(var(--p3) + 4px),grey calc(var(--p3) + 5px);
}
.camera::before,
.camera::after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:100%;
  width:50%;
  background: 
    linear-gradient( 126deg,var(--c1)) bottom right/var(--e1,40%) var(--e2,20%) no-repeat,
    linear-gradient( 162deg,var(--c1)) bottom      /100% var(--e3,60%) no-repeat, 
    
    linear-gradient(-162deg,var(--c1)),
    linear-gradient(-126deg,var(--c2)),      
    linear-gradient(-90deg, var(--c3)),      
    linear-gradient(-54deg ,var(--c2)),
    linear-gradient(-18deg ,var(--c1)); /* 36deg/2 then we increment by 36deg*/
}

.camera::after{
  transform:rotate(180deg);
  transform-origin:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="camera">
</div>
<div class="camera" style="--p1: 66.5%;--p2: 56%;--p3: 51%;  --e3: 51%;--e2: 8%;--e1: 13%;">
</div>

<div class="camera" style="--p1: 50%;--p2: 37%;--p3: 15%; --e3: 68%;--e2: 41%;--e1: 50%;">
</div>
```

6. Поскольку мы имеем дело с background, мы можем добавить
   дополнительный слой для изображения:

```css
#camera{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border:1px solid;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/id/155/800/800) center/80% 80%;
  --p1:60%;
  --p2:48%;
  --p3:38%;
  
  --c1: transparent var(--p1),#000 calc(var(--p1) + 1px) calc(var(--p1) + 3px),grey calc(var(--p1) + 4px);
  --c2: transparent var(--p2),#000 calc(var(--p2) + 1px) calc(var(--p2) + 3px),grey calc(var(--p2) + 4px);
  --c3: transparent var(--p3),#000 calc(var(--p3) + 1px) calc(var(--p3) + 3px),grey calc(var(--p3) + 4px);
}
#camera::before,
#camera::after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:100%;
  width:50%;
  background: 
    linear-gradient( 126deg,var(--c1)) bottom right/var(--e1,40%) var(--e2,20%) no-repeat,
    linear-gradient( 162deg,var(--c1)) bottom      /100% var(--e3,60%) no-repeat, 
    
    linear-gradient(-162deg,var(--c1)),
    linear-gradient(-126deg,var(--c2)),      
    linear-gradient(-90deg, var(--c3)),      
    linear-gradient(-54deg ,var(--c2)),
    linear-gradient(-18deg ,var(--c1)); /* 36deg/2 then we increment by 36deg*/
}

#camera::after{
  transform:rotate(180deg);
  transform-origin:right;
}
```

```html
<div id="camera">
</div>
<div id="camera" style="--p1: 66.5%;--p2: 56%;--p3: 51%;  --e3: 51%;--e2: 8%;--e1: 13%;">
</div>

<div id="camera" style="--p1: 50%;--p2: 37%;--p3: 15%; --e3: 68%;--e2: 41%;--e1: 50%;">
</div>
```

### Анимация затвора

7. И вот идея, как создать анимацию открытия / закрытия затвора:

```css
.camera{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border:1px solid;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/id/155/800/800) center/cover;
  --p1:60%;
  --p2:48%;
  --p3:38%;
  
  --c1: transparent var(--p1),#000 calc(var(--p1) + 1px) calc(var(--p1) + 4px),grey calc(var(--p1) + 5px);
  --c2: transparent var(--p2),#000 calc(var(--p2) + 1px) calc(var(--p2) + 4px),grey calc(var(--p2) + 5px);
  --c3: transparent var(--p3),#000 calc(var(--p3) + 1px) calc(var(--p3) + 4px),grey calc(var(--p3) + 5px);
}
.camera::before,
.camera::after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:-50%;
  left:50%;
  height:200%;
  width:100%;
  transition:.5s all linear;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(-126deg,var(--c1)) bottom left/var(--e1,40%) var(--e2,20%) no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(-162deg,var(--c1)) bottom      /100% var(--e3,60%) no-repeat, 
    
    linear-gradient(162deg,var(--c1)),
    linear-gradient(126deg,var(--c2)),      
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--c3)),      
    linear-gradient(54deg ,var(--c2)),
    linear-gradient(18deg ,var(--c1)); /* 36deg/2 then we increment by 36deg*/
}

.camera::after{
  transform:rotate(180deg);
  transform-origin:left;
}

.camera:hover::before,
.camera:hover::after {
  top:0;
  left:50%;
  height:100%;
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="camera">
</div>
```

### Альтернативное решение

8. Мы можем объединить код автора вопроса и идею двух симметричных
   фигур и создать его, как показано ниже:

```js
let partAmount = 10;
let cont = document.querySelector('.cont');
let parts = [];
for(let i = 1; i <= partAmount ; i++){
  let partCont = createElement('div','partCont');
  let part = createElement('div','part');
  parts.push(part);
  partCont.appendChild(part);
  cont.appendChild(partCont);
  partCont.style.transform = 'rotate('+ 360 / partAmount * i+'deg) translatey(-250px)';
}
function createElement(tag,className){
  let elem = document.createElement(tag);
  elem.classList.add(className);
  return elem;
}
/*added*/
let alt = cont.cloneNode(true);
document.querySelector('.dia').appendChild(alt);
```

```css
.cont{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  clip-path: polygon(0 -150px, 0 150px, -150px 150px,-150px -150px); /*added*/
}
.cont:last-child {
  transform:rotate(180deg); /*added*/
}
.dia{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position:relative;
}
.partCont{
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: left top;
}
.part{
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-bottom: 3px solid gray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: rotate(60deg);
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="dia">
  <div class="cont">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: да, забыл сказать, самый последний сниппет на айфоне не правильно работает

Comment: Саша а этот пример должен работать ?

Answer (score 13):

Специально посмотрел [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZDGP2bdogU), как устроена диафрагма.

На HTML+CSS сделать реалистично намного сложнее чем на SVG.

Вся сложность данного примера в подсчете координат конечной точки дуги, образующей границу створки диафрагмы.

Здесь я воспользовался одним наблюдением, не проверял работает ли оно в общем случае, для 6 створок работает идеально.

Эта точка лежит на окружности, построенной через точку крепления соседней по часовой стрелке створки, с таким же радиусом как и у ограничивающей окружности.

UPD: уменьшено кол-во изменений структуры документа, теперь фигуры имеют корректные форму и им добавлена заливка, соответственно они могут выполнять роль диафрагмы - закрывая собой другое изображение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
let r = 80, value = 0.5;
let arc = (x, y, sweep) => `A${r},${r},0,0,${sweep},${x},${y}`;
let paths = document.querySelectorAll('path');
paths.forEach((path, i) => path.setAttribute('fill', `hsl(${i*60},75%,55%)`))
requestAnimationFrame(draw);

function draw() {
  upd();
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function upd() {
  value = Math.min(0.98, Math.max(value, 0));
  paths.forEach((path, i) => {
    let rot = Math.PI*(0.5 + 2/paths.length),
      cx = Math.cos(rot)*r,
      cy = Math.sin(rot)*r,
      radians = Math.PI*value*2/paths.length,
      cos = Math.cos(radians),
      sin = Math.sin(radians),
      x = cx - cos*cx - sin * cy,
      y = cy - cos*cy + sin * cx;
    path.setAttribute('d', `M0,${r}${arc(x,y,1)}${arc(cx,cy,0)}${arc(0,r,0)}`);
    path.setAttribute('transform', `rotate(${i/paths.length*360})`);
  });
};

addEventListener('mousemove', e => value = e.y/innerHeight*1.2-0.1);
addEventListener('touchmove', e => value = e.touches[0].pageY/innerHeight*1.2-0.2);
```

```css
body, svg {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox=-100,-100,200,200 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
  <path></path><path></path><path></path><path></path><path></path><path></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: если увести мышку очень далеко, получается красота ( с зажатой кнопкой мыши левой )

Comment: @Stranger in the Q да, забыл сказать, что предыдущие версии были более реалистичны, по сравнению с радугой

Comment: @Alexandr_TT да но они были без заливки, и не закрывали контент за собой, тут я это исправил